# Where to use "even" in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

I have confusion about where to use only, even, just, etc.

I have two sentences,

> 1. They don't even listen to their mothers

> 2. They don't listen even to their mothers

Here, assume there are some kids. These kids don't listen to anyone. not even to their mothers.

Comment: I would add a comma after *listen* in the second sentence. That aside, they are both fine.

Comment: @JasonBassford so in my question, I should use "Here, assume there are some kids. These kids don't listen to anyone. even to their mothers." instead of "Here, assume there are some kids. These kids don't listen to anyone. not even to their mothers."

Comment: @JasonBassford there's no need to write "not" before even to their mothers

Comment: No. I mean: *2. They don't listen, even to their mother.* (It would be more natural to add *not* but, strangely, it means the same thing without it in this construction.)

Comment: @JasonBassford okay, thank you :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think even is a word that can almost always be taken out without changing the meaning of the sentence.

To me, the sentences have equivalent meaning. But in the example 'They don't listen, even to their mothers' includes the 'even to their mothers' as an afterthought. So the second example seems more conversational to me.

I hope that helps.